# The Coven baby blues

Tags: language-explanation, the-coven-elemental-magic

From the book: The Coven Elemental Magic

Page 7 -

"The whites of her eyes all but swallowed her baby blues"

Her baby blues is her eyes? How the whites of her eyes can swallow her baby blues?

Answer (score -1):

You're right. They can't.  Prior to about 1940, "baby blues" meant "eyes" with the suggestion that their owner was attractive. It's still used occasionally today, but sounds pretty dated.  The blue part referred, of course to the iris. (Oddly enough, it seems to have been used more widely than just for blue-eyed people.)

On the face of it, "The whites of her eyes all but swallowed her baby blues" is meaningless and may be just sloppy writing.   But if, in the context of the line in the novel (which we don't have here), the owner of the "baby blues" is afraid, it *might* be referring a bit clumsily to the eyes widening and showing more white, which could -- if you don't think about it too much -- be described as the whites swallowing up the irises.

Comment: Except that it's the pupil (the black part in the center) that widens and contracts, so the iris "gives up" area from the inside of the circle.  If the eyes were dilated, it would be the pupils that "swallowed her baby blues".  Without more context, I'd assume the author intended to imply that the (blue) irises were atypically smallish, compared to the whites of the eyes...perhaps a intended as a "more poetic" way to say "beady eyes", or to imply that the character is somewhat bug-eyed (less of the lid covering the white of the eyeball).

Comment: Is it not just saying that the character had very small irises, so that the sclera appeared to "swallow" the baby blue part?